# UI designing for multiple resolution in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, panel

Hi I am really new to Unity development.I have a canvas with following structure

[image]

Inspector for all the UI elements are as below

**For canvas**
[image]

**For Panel**

[image]

**For Inner Button**
[image]

I am checking this on my iPad pro 2020.Followings are the results.(The + button inside the panel). My question is the "+" button and panel's aspect ratio is different when changing from portrait to landscape. How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

**Portrait**
[image]

**Landscape**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you choose a canvas scaler type (width or height), should change dynamically with W/H ratio your device aspect ratio calculation as float value, also this value are related your device screen orientation. So you need to calculate seperately for portrait or landscape orientations. Differently you could use match mod with shrink and set value to minimum pixel ratio your sprites.

However, in some cases, you may need to create compatible image files in different resolution modes while designing for tablets.

These methods gives you a immutable screen visuals...

**Also, if you haven't read it, please read this thread and the related instructions.
[Multi Resolution](https://forum.unity.com/threads/canvas-scaler-scale-with-screen-size-same-as-setting-ui-objects-to-stretch.512005/)**